# Os.rename Files Overwrite

Tags: python

I am making a Python project that renames multiple files. However, sometimes the files overwrite.

```
suffixes = ['.pdf', '.epub', '.mobi']
file_list = []


def change_fname(dir_name, part=' (z-lib.org)', action='remove'):
    fnames = os.listdir(dir_name)
    for suffix in suffixes:
        fnames_suffix = [f for f in fnames if f.endswith(suffix)]
        for fname in fnames_suffix:
            print(f'{action} "{part}" into/from "{fname}"')
            if action == 'remove' and fname.endswith(part+suffix):
                new_name = fname[:-len(suffix) - len(part)] + suffix
                print(f'fname is {fname}')
            elif action == 'insert':
                new_name = fname[:-len(suffix)] + part + suffix
            else:
                raise Exception(f'Unknown Action: {action}')
            print(new_name)
            old_file = os.path.join(dir_name, fname)
            new_file = os.path.join(dir_name, new_name)
            os.rename(old_file, new_file)


file_to_show = '/Users/ChrisHart/Downloads/test i love you daddy/'
subprocess.call(["open", "-R", file_to_show])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dir_name = '/Users/ChrisHart/Downloads/test i love you daddy/'
    try:
        change_fname(dir_name, part=' (z-lib.org)', action='remove')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

This is my program ^

```
file (part).pdf
file.pdf

The file will delete " (part)", so we get this

file.pdf
file.pdf

And they overwrite.

file.pdf
```

How can I fix this overwriting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share with the code where you are renaming your file? It's pretty hard for us to figure out what is going wrong without actually being able to see what you are doing. Check out this article for best practices in sharing code here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a script that changes multiple files. Maybe my code helps you understand your problem:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())           #Gives you your current directory

os.chdir('/PATH/TO/FILES')   #Change directory to the files


for i in os.listdir('/PATH/TO/FILES'):
    os.rename(i, i.replace('(z-lib.org)', ' '))  #replaces z-lib with one whitespace
    
print(i)
```

I know what you're trying to replace :D ... I did the same thing